# Can file size be a negative number? Why?

Tags: posix, filesize

On `/coreutils-8.12/src/ls.c`, I've found this comment:

```
/* POSIX requires that a file size be printed without a sign, even
when negative.  Assume the typical case where negative sizes are
actually positive values that have wrapped around.  */
```

on line 2639.

My questions are: 
- What is this typical case they refer to? 
- Can file size be a negative number, other than in overflowing problems with BIG files and old systems?
- If yes, why?(and why should I care like they are doing in the comment above?)

I'm interested also in other systems, not only POSIX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may well mean that file sizes in POSIX should be treated as unsigned integers, not signed. A file size of > 2GB if represented as a 32-bit integer would appear negative, though it obviously isn't.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I understand this problem, which should be due to a simple overflow matter. Are they refering to it when saying "..positive values that have wrapped around"? I don't really understand this last phrase. My question was about other cases different than this one tough, if any even exists.

Comment: I think it's just a poorly worded way of saying that they're unsigned integers. It's a common-ish problem with C, whereby if you don't make the right choice between unsigned and signed integers, you can get misleading results. I think it was written by a techie who has trouble turning code concepts into English (which is a very common problem) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code below the comment:

```
static uintmax_t
unsigned_file_size (off_t size)
{
  return size + (size < 0) * ((uintmax_t) OFF_T_MAX - OFF_T_MIN + 1);
}
```

If `size` is negative, it will be changed to a positive number by adding some defined value (most likely something near 2^31 for 32 bit datatypes etc.).

This prevents typical errors like assigning a filesize of 2-4 GB to a signed integer which will result in a negative number which `ls` should display as the correct positive filesize instead.